# Free Math equation image generator

Tags: c#, math

I'm looking for a component that generates math equations. 
like what wikipedia has but for windows server.

if i enter x^2, it will generate a gif with proper formatting as output

It must run on IIS and .NET and not a web service from somewhere.

has anyone seen anything that does this?

Comment: Last time I had to do this I embedded a TCL parser in my C program and used the TCL/tk graph module thingy...

Comment: How complex will these equations be? Arithmetic and a few common functions (trig...), or real mathematical typesetting (e.g. the kind of thing appearing here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration)?

Comment: yes it will require real mathematical typesetting like the one on wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

[Check this out](http://www.codecogs.com/). They have a LaTeX like equation editor, and apparently the can compile their code with Visual Studio. You might be able to get something working related to your question.

Comment: where can i download the source? all i see is a web based eq editor

Comment: Read through the site, specifically the INSTALL section. It is all there. Of course, you also need to install LaTeX and PHP... But you can access it from your ASPX program. You could host the PHP/LaTeX part on the same, or different server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one option would be to write your own parser - i.e. that takes "x^2" and builds a .NET 3.5 `Expression` to do the same. Once you have an `Expression`, you can use `Compile()` to get a delegate (`Func<double,double>`, for example) that you can use to generate the points. That isn't a huge amount of work (it took me about 2 hours to write a similar (though basic) parser a few months ago).

Of course, you'd still need to worry about the imaging side... maybe the [.NET chart control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) released a few months ago? (it isn't just ASP.NET)

Comment: the .NET chart control looks interesting. but i didn't see anything for formatting equations

Answer (score 0):

I am using [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to generate equations in websites, 
basically I write HTML. I've had no problems with it.